# random_state in random forest

Tags: python, data-science, random-forest, random-seed

I just learned how to use the machine learning model Random Forest; however, although I read about the random_state parameter, I couldn't understand what it does. For example, what is the difference between `random_state = 0`   and   `random_state = 300`
Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 0):

`train_test_split` splits arrays or matrices into random train and test subsets. That means that everytime you run it without specifying random_state, you will get a different result, this is expected behavior.
When you use `random_state=any_value` then your code will show exactly same behaviour when you run your code.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, most people use the number 42 when we use random_state.

For example, random_state = 42 and there's a reason for that.
Below is the answer.

The number 42 is, in The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy by Douglas Adams, the "Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything", calculated by an enormous supercomputer named Deep Thought over a period of 7.5 million years. Unfortunately, no one knows what the question is

Answer (score 0):

Random forests introduce stochasticity by randomly sampling data and features. Running RF on the exact same data may produce different outcomes for each run due to these random samplings. Fixing the seed to a constant i.e. 1 will eliminate that stochasticity and will produce the same results for each run.